# Bloquear o acesso direto a uma página com php

Tags: php, htaccess, session

Estou fazendo uma página de login onde o usuário, ao fazer login em index.php ele vai pra painel.php
Eu consegui bloquear o acesso ao painel.php com SESSION, porém se eu acessar conexao.php (onde tem as informações do banco de dados) ou login.php (onde tem as query), consigo acessar uma página em branco.

Usei o seguinte código em login2.php:

```
if(!$_SESSION['login']) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

Se o usuário não tiver feito login, ao tentar acessar direto a página painel.php, ele é retornado ao index.php

Tentei fazer isso para o conexao.php e login.php, porém, aconteceu o obvio, quando o usuário clica no botão para fazer login, ele não sai da index.php.

A página login.php e conexao.php é somente uma página em branco com querys e dados de conexao com a DB, porém, não quero que o usuário tenha acesso a elas.

Tentei com .htaccess mas com ele, o usuário também não consegue fazer login.

Existe alguma maneira de impedir que acessem diretamente login.php e conexao.php sem atrapalhar o login e o redirecionamento pra painel.php após o login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma das maneiras de fazer este controle é através do PHP.

Encontrei a solução para o seu problema em outra [Pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999475/prevent-direct-url-access-to-php-file/33999539) stackoverflow em inglês.

Porém vou explicar o funcionamento do código que foi escolhido pela comunidade como correto.

Fiz algumas alterações do código da resposta para motivos didáticos.

```
<?php
    // Verifica o método de requisição HTTP e o local de execução do script PHP
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && realpath(__FILE__) == realpath( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) ) {
       // Quando entrar nessa condição, significa que o usuário tentou acessar o link diretamente
       // Faça algo.
        die();    
    }
```

**Explicação:**
O usuário ao tentar acessar o link direto pelo browser, no seu caso {$path}/login.php, sempre enviará uma requisição com o método HTTP GET que irá cumprir a **primeira regra** do condicional.

**A segunda regra** do condicional está verificando se o arquivo que está sendo executado (login.php) é igual ao arquivo atualmente em execução.

No caso ao realizar qualquer requisição para o seu login.php, a regra irá ser **TRUE**, pois as variáveis terão valores iguais.

Porém você ainda pode utilizar o método **POST** para receber os dados no login.php e realizar a autenticação do seu usuário. ( nunca utilize GET passando informações confidenciais ).

Para a questão do **conexão.php**, se você estiver utilizando apenas um include/require, você pode diminuir a condicional e retirar a primeira regra que verifica o método HTTP e utilizar apenas a regra do path.

```
 <?php
      // Verifica o local de execução do script PHP
      if ( realpath(__FILE__) == realpath( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) ) {
          // Quando entrar nessa condição, significa que o usuário tentou acessar o link diretamente    
          // Faça algo.
           die();        
        }
```

Pois utilizando include/require sempre terá valores diferentes para as duas variáveis. Caso tentem o acesso direto, as variáveis terão valores iguais.

Comment: Deu certo, a página de conexao.php tem os dados da DB,  servidor, login, senha, nome, então não posso usar o método GET, porque está passando informações confidenciais? Já no login.php eu posso usar, porque está apenas consultando o banco de dados para verificar se o usuário e senha existe?

Comment: Lucas, o ideal é nunca utilizar o método GET para enviar informações confidenciais.

Ao enviar uma requisição com o método GET, os valores serão enviados através de Query Strings, e a sua url ficaria assim: **/login.php?usuario=fulano&senha=12345**.
Isso pode possibilitar que alguém que não deveria ter as credênciais descubra o acesso através da URL. Por isto a recomendação é sempre usar o método POST.